# ImageIO: CreateMetadataFromXMPBufferInternal Threw error

Tags: ios, image

My iPad app keeps displaying this message in the log.......

```
<Error>: ImageIO: CreateMetadataFromXMPBufferInternal  Threw error #203 (Duplicate property or field node)
```

It doesn't seem to have any functional effect on the application. I've Googled the error, only returns about 5 hits and none of them apply to iOS.

Any idea what is causing it and how to handle it / stop it logging?

Comment: Did you investigate further? I came up with the same log.

Comment: Afraid not MrBr, I did as much digging as I could, drew a blank so posted the question here.

Comment: I just started getting this error with Xcode 5.1+, it wasn't there when I upgraded the app to iOS 7 around 6-8 months ago.

Comment: It has to do with Exif, I think.  The camera used to take pictures did not insert all expected keys (i.e. make).

Comment: I'm seeing this error with `AFNetworking`. Tried the accepted answer with no luck.

Comment: I turned off my always break on exception, this happens to me on occasion when I'm using the category UIImageView+WebCache.h

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just struggled with the same issue. It seems to happen in iOS7 when you attempt to read JPEG files using `imageWithContentsOfFile`.

As a workaround i switched to using `imageWithData`:

```
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path]; 
if(data)   
  return [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Answer (score 2):

We had this problem because we had a .jpg file which was really a .png file saved with the wrong extension. Does it open properly with an image editing tool such as Photoshop? That was the key clue for us, is that it gave a parsing error reading opening in Photoshop.

Comment: Initially upvoted this answer because it was occurring with a PNG, but I discovered it's actually happening on a call to CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, 0, NULL) with a JPG. Can't remove upvote.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same error, but I'm using Corona SDK, so I cannot use the suggested solution because I'm not programing with Objective-C

ElTomato suggested in previous comments that the problem is with exif info, so I used an optimizer tool (Imageoptim.com) to remove exif info on jpg images. Imageoptim is a free program that removes exif info and comments, also it tries to find the best compression parameters.

I had the problem with my background images, in fact the problem was when I tried to setup a new background for the application. The application was working but the error was there. When I used the ImageOptim tool to remove exif info on my background images the app worked without error message.

Comment: You should add details of how you achieved what you described. As it stands this barely meets the criteria for an answer.

Comment: Backs up the suggestion that missing exif data.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran across this problem.

The original image was from an iPhone 5s. The image was created in my program without the warning mentioned above.

I loaded the image into gimp 2.8 (Mac) and immediately exported it. The image threw this warning when loaded it into my program.

Then I reloaded the original into gimp and exported it with a new name and under Advance Options I unchecked Save XMP Data. The exported image loaded into my program without the warning.

These images all had exifs and my program had no problems reading them. Don't know if they were using XMP (Extensible Metadata Platform) but I can live without it.